# A proof that if the product of spaces is Hausdorff, each of them is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Is my approach to this question right?

**Question:**

Prove that if $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha (\neq \emptyset) $$ is Hausdorff, each $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff.

**Attempt to answer:**

It is enough to show that if there is a $X_i,i\in J$ that is not Hausdorff, then $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$$ is not Hausdorff.
$$\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$$ is homeomorphic to $$\prod_{\alpha \in J/\{i\}} X_\alpha \times X_i,i\in J $$ so it is sufficient to show that a product of **two** spaces is Hausdorff only if both are Hausdorff (which is easy).

Am I right?

Comment: seems like you're pretty much there :)

Comment: The claim is false. $\emptyset \times X = \emptyset$ is Hausdorff for every $X$. This is the only exception: If $X_i$ are non-empty spaces such that $\prod_i X_i$ Hausdorff, then each $X_i$ is Hausdorff. PS: Don't go for an indirect proof for no reason, this makes life only more complicated.

Comment: good spot, didn't see that

Comment: Are you using the product topology on $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg thanks. I'l edit that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reduction works, but it is better and faster to just write down the proof in general.

Let $j \in J$. Take  two points $a,b \in X_j$. Since all other $X_i$ are non-empty, [choose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice) some $x_i \in X_i$. We get two points $i \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{c} a \text{ (resp. } b \text{)} &  i = j \\ x_i & i \neq j \end{array}\right.$ in $\prod_i X_i$. By assumption they may be separated by disjoint open neighborhoods, say $\prod_i U_i$ and $\prod_i V_i$. Then $U_j,V_j$ separate $a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

The space $X_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\Pi_i X_i$, namely the subspace obtained by fixing a choice of an element of $X_i$ for each $i \ne \alpha$. Since a subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff, it follows that $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: nice! but do you think my reduction works?

Comment: Yes, I think your reduction is valid.